# ambari blueprint installtion failed on - config types are not defined in the stack

Tags: json, stack, ambari, blueprint, hdp

I'm unable to register blueprints to install Ambari multinode cluster .

I have used the below blueprints :

```
curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X POST -u admin:admin http://$server:8080/api/v1/blueprints/HDP_PROD?validate_topology=false -d @/home/blueprint.json
```

I'm getting the below error ,

```
  "status" : 400,
  "message" : "Topology validation failed: org.apache.ambari.server.topology.InvalidTopologyException: The following config types are not defined in the stack: [hdfs-logsearch-conf, hive-logsearch-conf, mapred-logsearch-conf, spark2-logsearch-conf, ams-logsearch-conf, zookeeper-logsearch-conf, yarn-logsearch-conf, kafka-logsearch-conf] "
```

`Ambari` and `HDP` version are:

```
Ambari version – 2.7.4
HDP version 3.1.4
```

In the blueprint jaon files we have the

```
hdfs-logsearch-conf
hive-logsearch-conf, 
mapred-logsearch-conf,
spark2-logsearch-conf,
ams-logsearch-conf,
zookeeper-logsearch-conf,
yarn-logsearch-conf,
kafka-logsearch-conf
```

but not clearly why API failed on:

```
The following config types are not defined in the stack
```

is it means that stak on `ambari 2.7.4` not include - logsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about logsearch files

logsearch-conf.xml files are removed as part of jira `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-21212`.

These are removed as xml files are not used for configuration.